# Cancel SQL *PLUS Execution without raising an error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

i have a tricky SQL Problem:

We have a huge SQL Script which installs our application on the DB server.

We want to skip the database installation if the latest update didn't change anything in the DB.

I have implemented following check, which is executed before the other SQL commands:

**check_current_version_delta.sql:**

```
DECLARE
  v_deploy_version       VARCHAR2(30) := '&db_deploy_version';
  v_check                BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Check if we have a new DB version');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
    FOR cu_version IN (SELECT version FROM &DB_CURRENT_USER..db_deployment WHERE version = v_deploy_version AND ROWNUM = 1) LOOP
      v_check := TRUE;
    END LOOP;
    IF v_check THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'DB Version: '||v_deploy_version||' is already installed');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

This is working very well but our installation team complains about the ORA-XXXXX Error in the log, because they have automated error checks this installation is marked as FAIL (though there was no actual error)

**So now the actual problem:**

I need to cancel the execution of the SQL without any errors in the LOG. Is this even possible?

Alternative would be to make the rest of the installation dependent on the outcome of the script above. But i'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Have you some suggestions on how to handle it *the good way*?

Comment: I'm curious what the two dots in `&DB_CURRENT_USER..db_deployment` mean. I have never seen that syntax (only with a single dot, e.g. `&DB_CURRENT_USER.db_deployment`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to create three scripts: The first checks for the condition and either calls the second or the third. The second does the real job. The third is an empty dummy, to avoid the error message cause by calling a non-existent script

In code, it looks like this:

```
col SCRIPT1_COL new_val SCRIPT1

SELECT case
        when version = '&db_deploy_version' then 'dummy.sql'
        else 'upgrade_db.sql'
       end as SCRIPT1_COL
    FROM &DB_CURRENT_USER..db_deployment;

@&SCRIPT1
```

Alternatively, you could use the method shown above to load either a script "dummy.sql" that does nothing or a script "exit.sql" that just contains the `exit` command, and execute it before doing the real job.

Comment: +1, Was just about to write the exact same thing, (Thought I was the only one who knew about `new_val`).

Comment: Well, I think I found that in StackOverflow a few weeks ago when I had a similar problem.

Comment: It's also useful for accepting blank variables into scripts. I use in all my utility scripts for filtering by user and or owner etc ...

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me. But since the table db_deployment contains several entries (many of which cause the condition to choose upgrade_db.sql) i needed to limit the output to one row only (the latest one) with: FROM (select * from &DB_CURRENT_USER..db_deployment where rownum = 1 order by &DB_CURRENT_USER..db_deployment.OID desc);

Comment: @bigbasti I expected that you would have to adjust the SQL query a bit to fit your specific needs, but I didn't want to overcomplicate it with details that have no meaning for other users.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you're already using `whenever sqlerror` so make it terminate when you raise that exception, and you're redirecting the output to your log file. If so you can just hide the text of the exception with `set termout off`:

```
whenever sqlerror exit success
set termout off

DECLARE
   ...
BEGIN
    ...
    IF v_check THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001,
        'DB Version: '||v_deploy_version||' is already installed');
    END IF;
END;
/

set termout on
whenever sqlerror exit failure

... the rest of your script
```

The script will stop if the exception is raised but produce no output. The `success` means anything that runs this won't decide it has errored independently of the log; the exit code from `sqlplus` will be zero.

You may be spooling to output instead; in which case just don't start the spool until after your check. Or if you have things before this that you do have to spool, turn the spool off and then on again afterwards with `append`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks also very good, but we choose the first solution since it worked better with the other scripts